# Jow to use str_to_date

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to use str_to_date function in MySql and return the correct date. Below is my try and and I am getting syntax error.

```
 SELECT STR_TO_DATE('011122143859',%d%c%Y%l%i%S);
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%d%c%Y%l%i%S)' at line 1.
```

I need to return the timestamp value as 2022-11-01 14:38:59

Can someone show me what would be the correct syntax. I followed this resource.
https://database.guide/str_to_date-examples-mysql/

Update:

I found the correct syntax as below.

```
STR_TO_DATE('011122143859','%d%m%y%H%i%S')
```

Comment: %d%c%Y%l%i%S needs to be quoted ie '%d%c%Y%l%i%S' and as is in the linked examples

Comment: @P.Salmon, Tried already.. It provides output as NULL

Comment: Study https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format to get correct parameters NB question is about syntax error..

Comment: @Thanx.. This is the correct syntax STR_TO_DATE('011122143859','%d%m%y%H%i%S')

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE("2017,8,14 10,40,10", "%Y,%m,%d %h,%i,%s");
```

OR

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE("August,5,2017", "%M %e %Y");
```

Comment: OP is trying to convert '011122143859'

Comment: This is not what I present in the example. Need to know how to do for provided type of string